# Put an image in a shape - Word VBA

Tags: vba, image, ms-word, shapes

I've created this code to find the shape in the Word document to change the image it contains.

I can find the shape by using the shape name (Oval 47), but I'm not confident with that. I'd like to reach the shape by using the alternative text "Portrait".

It worked at first, but now when finding the shape with this alternative text, it skips the code. Why?

```
For Each shp In doc.Shapes
    shp.Select
    Debug.Print Selection.ShapeRange.Name & " = " & Selection.ShapeRange.AlternativeText
        
    If Selection.ShapeRange.AlternativeText = "Portrait" Then
        MsgBox "portrait"
        For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
            With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
                .UserPicture vrtSelectedItem
            End With
            Exit Sub
        Next vrtSelectedItem
    End If
Next shp
```

Comment: Are there more such shapes (having the same `Name` and `alternativeText`)?

Comment: Make sure that the AlternativeText does not contain extra spaces or a carriage return.  Also, note that the comparison is case-sensitive.

Comment: Thank you. 
There are no shapes with the same name or alternative text.
And I've taken into account that it is case-sensitive.

Comment: Did you check for extra spaces and/or carriage return?

Comment: Yes, I;'ve checked and everything seems to be fine. Thank you.